# Create Multiview Views/page based on amounts of rows in database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, multiview

Hello and thanks for reading this.

Here is a preview of my Database table:

[image]

I would like to make my code automatic/dynamic add 1 view in my Multiview foreach row that exits in the datatable and fill in the information that I want each page to show.

I was able to do it with a listview but eveytime i switch page in the list view it do a postback ofcourse and delete any data I typed in the previous "page".

So if we take the data table and use that as an example there should be 2 Vies in my Multiview.

Is it posible to Make something like this?

Believe it or not, i spend about 2 hours of searching and testing code but cant make it work so now im asking you awesome people.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what exactly you want to do is - add new view for each row in multiview, right ??? and also want to maintain it in postback ??

Comment: Not 100% I want to Create a viewpage INSIDE the multiview foeach row in my database table